# Getting images from instagram using MIN_TIMESTAMP and MSX_TIMESTAMP

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I am trying to get images from instagram using between two days. But iam getting wrongly.

I wrote the code like beolw:

```
NSString * fromDate = @"2014 Aug 14 10:00:00";
NSString * toDate = @"2014 Aug 14 14:00:00";
NSDateFormatter * dateFmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFmt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate * time1 = [dateFmt dateFromString:fromDate];
NSDate * time2 = [dateFmt dateFromString:toDate];
int fromInterval = [time1 timeIntervalSince1970];
int toInterval = [time2 timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"FROM %d  TO %d",fromInterval,toInterval);//
NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/%@/media/recent?count=33&&MIN_TIMESTAMP=%dMAX_TIMESTAMP=%d&client_id=CLIENT_ID",hashTag, fromInterval,toInterval];
NSURL *urlInstagram=[NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlInstagram];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
NSLog(@"respionse %@",json);
```

But its not giving result what i expect. Its returning 16th Aug posts only.

Answer (score 0):

According to their api page http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/, 
/tags/media/recent doesn't accept min_timestamp nor max_timestamp

One solution is to get tag images (using count if are many) and filter based on created_time